# Java - ArrayIndexOutOfBounds while testing shows it's not

Tags: java, exception, indexing

need some help with my code, it's giving me arrayindexoutofbounds 0 exception when I try to run it and it points to "results[counter]=random; " line, and the system.out.println line i wrote just before it correctly prints "Counter is 0 and numToss is 5 and random is 0(or 1)"

```
   public int[] results = new int[numToss];

   public void fillArray() {
      int counter = 0;
      //int[] results = new int[numToss];
      int random;
      while (counter < (numToss)) {
        if (Math.random() > 0.5) random = 1;
        else random = 0;
        System.out.println("Counter is " + counter + " and numToss is " + numToss + " and random is " + random);
        results[counter]=random; 
        counter++;
      }
   }
```

Comment: Please construct a complete test-case.

Answer (score 2):

> arrayindexoutofbounds 0 exception

This can only mean one thing, that the results array has a size of 0.

Note that you are testing the value of numtoss when the fillArray method is called, and it's giving you a non-zero value, but **this doesn't matter**. No, what matters is its value **when you create the results array**, and numToss is likely zero when you create the results array.

Solution: make sure numToss has a meaningful non-zero value when you create the results array.

---

**Edit**
Perhaps you would like assign but not re-declare the variable to do this:

```
public void fillArray() {
   //int[] results = new int[numToss];
   results = new int[numToss];  // do not re-declare this variable!

   for (int counter = 0; counter < results.length; counter++) {
     results[counter] = (Math.random() > 0.5) ? 1 : 0; 
   }
}
```

Alternatively, you could re-declare the variable and have your method return the int array created.

```
public int[] fillArray() {
   int[] results = new int[numToss];

   for (int counter = 0; counter < results.length; counter++) {
     results[counter] = (Math.random() > 0.5) ? 1 : 0; 
   }
   return results;
}
```

Note: this is one reason why you should use a for loop when iterating through an array as this totally avoids ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsExceptions.

Also, since your results array appears to only hold 2 values, consider making it an array of booleans and not ints.

Comment: I'm using one class to test and one to do all the work, the code i shown is from cointoss class which has cointoss constructor which takes in one int that represents the number of cointosses, i create new CoinToss object in testing class and then call from there FillArray(), does that have anything to do with it?

Comment: @user2627736: who knows because all we've been given are code snippets. All I can tell by what you've posted is what I tell you above. If you need further help, then you will need to create and post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example Program](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).